# Reloading page in single page application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

I am in the middle of building a single page application. I am in a situation in which I have a slider in one tab and implemented a google map api in another tab. I have implemented the slider using bootstrap carousel. Now since this is a single page application when I am routing from one tab to another tab, slider is not working neither google map is coming up. And after reloading the page everything is working fine.

I am trying find an alternate solution for this one. I am trying to reload the tab once again once it's clicked.

```
<li class="nav-item">
   <a ng-click="reloadRoute()" class="nav-link" href="#/contact">Contact Us</a>
</li>
```

And in controller this is what I am trying

```
$scope.reloadRoute = function() {
       $route.reload();
    }
```

But it's not working.
After following the post and also the documentation looks like it's not possible to reload a single page in single page application once the entire application is loaded. Is there any alternate solution for this ? I am using AngularJS version `1.5.9`

Comment: Have you considered ng-map - it solves your problem.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I am not using it. I have directly added map in controller. Will it solve the problem ?

Comment: Yes, solves many problems with maps + AngularJS

Comment: @RandyCasburn what about slider ?

Comment: Pick one: http://ngmodules.org/modules?query=slider

Comment: @RandyCasburnthis link doesn't contain the image slider like galleries this is different one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be wiser to learn how to integrate Google maps and the slider with the AngularJS framework than to reload the entire page.

If you must reload the page, use `$window.location.reload(true)`.

For more information, see [MDN Web API Reference - Location.reload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload)

Comment: Isn't there any way to use the bootstrap in single page application ?

Comment: Of course there are ways to integrate Bootstrap with the AngularJS framework. Check out [UI Bootstrap - Bootstrap components written in pure AngularJS by the AngularUI Team](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/).

Comment: I followed this link but in carousel there is one line `image: '//unsplash.it/' + newWidth + '/300',` I am not sure about. Is it asking for the directive where the images are ?

Comment: The answer here is for "Reloading page in single page application". If you have another question, put it in a new question.